# Get Response from server using curl -IsH

Tags: php, curl

how can I add that parameter ("-IsH) to curl using PHP?

Comment: What do the parameters represent? Which ones didn't you find corresponding [`curl_setopt()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) constants for?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this depending on what header you want to add:

-I means only the header, no body

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_NOBODY);
```

-H

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'X-Apple-Tz: 0',
'X-Apple-Store-Front: 143444,12'
));
```

-s means silent